# is log4cxx supports http or https appenders?

Tags: c++, http, log4cxx

In log4j 2 documents I am found http appender details to support http.
But I am not able to find any information on http appender in log4cxx.

is there any workaround for log4cxx to support http or https appender?

Comment: Why are you using a logging library to do web requests? Wasn't log4j in the news recently for this exact problem? Try [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) instead.

Comment: you probably need to write your own appender, there is a socket appender though: https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/classlog4cxx_1_1net_1_1SocketAppender.html